# why is this error coming Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'created' of undefined in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

1. this is the code I've implemented in vue.js
2. I was trying to add a new employee to the firebase database.
3. the code was working until I wrote the methods and initialized the data section
4. when I tried going back steps where the code was running it was still giving runtime error

```
<template>
  

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <center><h1>New Employee</h1></center>
    <form @submit.prevent="adds" class="form">
      <label>Enter Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-modle="name">
      <label>Enter Employee ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-modle="emp_id">
      <label>Enter Department</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-modle="dep">
      <label>Enter Position</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-modle="position" >
      <router-link to="/" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Cancel</router-link>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import db from '../components/firebaseinit.js'
export default {
  name:"newEmployee",
  data(){
    return{
       name: null,
       emp_id: null,
       dep: null,
       position: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    adds(){
        db.collection('employee').add({
          emp_id: parseInt(this.emp_id),
          name: this.name,
          dep: this.dep,
          position: this.position
        }).then(this.router.push("/")).catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: change `then(this.router.push("/"))` into this:  `then(()=> this.router.push("/"))`

Comment: I tried your solution it's giving out the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I found the problem with my code at line 42

```
then(this.router.push("/")).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

2. The right way to call router is by $ the code would be replaced by

```
then(() => this.$router.push("/")).catch(err => console.log(err))
```